# Postgresql Multi Table Count: likes, dislikes, comments for social media style app

Tags: postgresql

Trying to build a query in postgresql to pull comments, likes, and dislikes out for a 'post'.  Currently, the query is miscounting, and seems to give extra values when both comments/likes occur for the same post.

SQLFiddle is available here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e0f51/1

Currently, the results look like this:

```
postid  postbody      comment_count dislikes    likes
1       Test Post A   1             0           0 
2       Test Post B   2             2           4
3       Test Post C   0             0           0
4       Test Post D   2             4           2
5       Test Post E   0             1           3
```

But should ideally look like this:

```
postid  postbody      comment_count dislikes    likes
1       Test Post A   1             0           0 
2       Test Post B   2             1           2
3       Test Post C   0             0           0
4       Test Post D   2             2           1
5       Test Post E   0             1           3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue will occur when there is more than 1 comment,   the like/dislike will be multiplied by the amount of comments received.

Best way round this,   is to nest the  like/dislike  into sub queries rather the joins...

```
SELECT posts.postid, posts.postbody,
  COUNT(DISTINCT comments.commentid) AS comment_count, 
  (SELECT COUNT(nullif(postlikes.vote,true)) FROM postlikes WHERE postlikes.postid=posts.postid)  AS dislikes, 
  (SELECT COUNT(nullif(postlikes.vote,false))FROM postlikes WHERE postlikes.postid=posts.postid)  AS likes 
  FROM posts 
  LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.postid=posts.postid 
  GROUP BY posts.postid;
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!  I was having a hard time figuring out where the multiples were coming from.  I don't mind the sub queries, and this seems to work perfectly.  Appreciate it!

Comment: and what If I want to add additional column (ex: user) to include the email, first_name and last_name from the user that created the post.. 
If I add any additional columns, I have to include them to either aggregate function or group by statement